# Is the Google SignIn framework available with mac catalyst support?

Tags: google-signin

I am looking for the google signin sdk with mac catalyst support. Current version of 5.0.1 also don't support catalyst. Is there any planned release for the same?

Answer (score 0):

Google Support has mentioned the [following](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/22CYQS7XIxA) regarding Mac Catalyst:

> We cannot provide technical assistance regarding your concern as the Mac Catalyst is not supported by the Mobile Ads SDK. To get future updates regarding this, please keep an eye on our [blog](https://www.blog.google/products/admob).